# How to prepare the object before request to be compatible with the requirements of the service?

Tags: javascript, rest, typescript

When the service requires an object like in method to change name:

```
{
  user: {
    data: {
      name: string
    }
  }
}
```

but, I have object like

```
{
  user: {
    age: 18,
    height: 150,
    weight: 80
    data: {
      name: 'John',
      surname: 'Juhn'
    }
  }
}
```

How do I prepare for an object to be compatible with service?

remove unwanted properties with a copy of an object in order not to lose data?

eg.

```
export function removeUnnecessaryProperty(object: Object, ...necessaryKeys: string[]) {

  Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
    if (necessaryKeys.indexOf(key) < 0) { delete object[key]; };
  });
}

let objectToRequest = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));
removeUnnecessaryProperty(objectToRequest.data, 'name');
removeUnnecessaryProperty(objectToRequest, 'data');
```

create a new object only with the required properties?

eg.

```
export function createObjectWithProperty(object: Object, ...Keys: string[]) {
  let newObject: Object = {};
  Keys.map(key => {
    newObject[key] = object[key];
  });
  return newObject
}
let objectToRequest = {data: undefined}
objectToRequest.data = createObjectWithProperty(object.data, 'name');
```

or send an object with additional properties?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you need to pass the exact number of properties.

Why? Don't pass any data that your service doesn't require. Besides this if an hacker can catch your data, he/she will get only that data, not all data.

Think a case when I need to pass only `user's name` to my `Web Api`. But my object contains also the `email`. Why the hacker need also get the `email`? With `name` he can't do anything, but with `mail` he can do many other things.